# Execute javascript from python 3 with arguments client side

Tags: javascript, python

Edit 2: I'm realizing more and more that this might be a hack that I am looking for, which most likely wont work considering companies work to prevent code injection. Now I wouldn't say this is code injection but more of the lines of variable injection. If anyone has any insight on this problem please provide it :) Thanks

I have searched around a bit but haven't really found what I am looking for.

I have this project in which there is a excel file with a bunch of numbers. I need to take these numbers and one by one search in a system. This system is based on HTML and javascript.

My question is, how can I with python 3 take these numbers and make a search in this system. The search function on the website is a javascript and I am not sure on how I can execute that javascript with my number as a argument.

Edit: I find my original text to be misleading so I have tried to make it more understandable and made a small 1,2,3 step of how the project is suppose to work and some text to explain whats happening.

1.Take data from excel cell A:1

2.Input the data in a closed search system

3.Based on the output set customer status to 1 or 0

4.Input the binary status in excel file B:1(0,1)

4.Take data from excel cell A:2

5.Rinse and repeat

The closed system I am talking about is a billing system for clients at a company I work for.
The search function is written in HTML/javascript
I want to use python as much as possible in this project as I am most comfortable with it.
I want to extract the data from excel using python (and xlsxwriter).
This data is then to be injected into a website containing a javascript search function.
Python will then extract the output of that search function and determine the binary status of the search. (if the client is active in our systems or not)

The reason for this is because we sometimes get these huge excel files of 300+ customers that we need to handle in some way. 
Many of these customers are inactive and I want to subtract these customers from the file and potentially reducing the customers per file by 100-150.

If there is any questions or confusing about what I want to accomplish please ask. Thank you for helping out!

The code below is taken directly from the closed billing system and I have no way to impact that code directly.

```
 HTML
 <input name="pointId" value="" size="28" onkeypress="return validatePointId(this.form, event);"> 

Javascript
function validateProductId(productObj,event){
//Trim the space in the begining and end of the string.
var productIdValue  = productObj.value;
var productIdTrim = productIdValue.replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
var digExp = /^[0-9]$/;
var notPresent= false;
    if ( event.keyCode == 13  || event.which == 13 ) {  
for (var i=0;i<productIdTrim.length;i++){
    if (!digExp.test(productIdTrim.charAt(i))){
                            notPresent = true;
                    }
}
if (notPresent){
    alert("Format: 0000000");
    productObj.value = "";
    productObj.focus();
    return false;
}else{
     productObj.value = productIdTrim;
     submit();
}
}

    }
function validateProductIdOnclick(productObj,currentFormObj,event){
        //Trim the space in the begining and end of the string.
       if ( event.keyCode == 13  || event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 0 || event.which == 0 ) 
       { 
        var productIdValue  = document.getElementById(productObj).value;
        var productIdTrim = productIdValue.replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
        var digExp = /^[0-9]$/;
        var notPresent= false;
        if (productIdValue != "")
    {
           for (var i=0;i<productIdTrim.length;i++){
                if (!digExp.test(productIdTrim.charAt(i))){
                                notPresent = true;
                        }
           }
    }
        else
    {
      alert("Inget produktinstansID är angivet.");
           document.getElementById(productObj).value = "";
           document.getElementById(productObj).focus();
           return false;
    }
        if (notPresent){
           alert("Format: 0000000");
           document.getElementById(productObj).value = "";
       document.getElementById(productObj).focus();
       return false;
        }else{
           document.getElementById(productObj).value = productIdTrim;
       currentFormObj.submit();
        }
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is always option to use Node.js,more [python,node.js](http://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2015/08/21/python-nodejs-comm/)

Then write your program as .js file and execute it using the subprocess.
More about [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess)

Comment: Im not 100% how that would help me. I read but didn't completely understand. I understand the part of using subprocess to execute a file, but I am not good at all in javascript so how would I then write a js file which can inject specific values into a websites script? I hope im not making this too confusing for you :)

Comment: Could yo post your project on the web,will try to solve it next couple of days.

Comment: I have edited my original post and given a more detailed explanation on what it is I want to achieve. Thank you for helping me :) Oh and yes, I would like to learn from this, I am not simply seeking someone to do the work for me but I am hoping to learn from this also.

Comment: I want to learn also!1. step easy,you save your data as csv.Then do you know how to read that csv file into your closed system?

Comment: First step is easy, im planning on using xlsxwriter for it. My main problem is how I can inject data from python to a javascript function. As I said I do not have access to the server or able to manipulate the javascript code. I'm only client sided.

Comment: I have not worked with node.js,but it can be used exactly for that,client side.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna take a closer look at node.js then.